# php get array from android

Tags: java, php, android

my code on php:

```
<?php
$username ='root';
$password ='abc';
$hostname ='localhost';
$database ='test_xmpp'; 
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or 
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database,$localhost);
$groupmates = array();
$abc=mysql_query('SELECT count(1) FROM groupchat');
$groupcount= mysql_result($abc,0);
$groupcount = $groupcount + 1;
echo $groupcount;
$admin = $_POST["admin"];
$groupname = $_POST["groupname"];
$groupmates = $_POST["groupmates"];
$sql="INSERT INTO groupchat (idgroupchat,groupname) VALUES       ('$groupcount','$groupname')";
mysql_query($sql);

$b = '2';

$a = $groupmates[0];
$sql1="INSERT INTO groupuser (idgroup, username, admin) VALUES ('$groupcount','$a','$b')";
mysql_query($sql1);
?>
```

my code on android:

```
 public static class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("admin", admin));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("groupname", groupname));
     for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
     {
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("groupmates",groupmates[i]));
     }
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.102/webservice/issertgroup.php");
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

question: `$groupmates[0]` is null. how can i get the array passing from the android??

i fail with using this method. please help me to solve this. i have searched a lot of references in google, but still cannot solve my problem.

Comment: new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2); is wrong it should be 10 as you have for loop 8 times and other 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

Pass parameter as array element from android/java, as below.

```
for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("groupmates["+i+"]",groupmates[i]));
}
```

It will simply pass an array in POST, so in PHP you can get it as below:

```
<?php
$groupmates=$_POST['groupmates'];
// echo $groupmates[0];
// echo $groupmates[1];  <--process your elements as normal array.
?>
```

**Method 2:**

You should use json encoded string of your array. (I'm not an android guy, so can't provide snippet to convert array to json but its easy task, you probably should knew it.)

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("groupmates",jsonGroupmates));
```

and in php use following:

```
$groupmates=json_decode($_POST['groupmates']);
```

That should work.